# Не работают ссылки Angular вставленные js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular2, angular4

Есть приложение Angular 4. В нем не работаю ссылки вставленные js-ом.Точнее они работают но перезагружают приложение полость, чего быть не должно.

Пример:
такая ссылка вставленная сразу в html компонента будет работать нормально

```
<li><a href="#" routerLink ="/inventory/item/0">item0</a></li>
```

но если к примеру js-ом куда либо вставить ссылку , будет работать, но перезагружает все приложение.

```
<a href="/inventory/item/'+data+'">'+data+'</a>
```

или так (работать не будет)

```
<a routerLink ="/inventory/item/'+data+'" href="#">'+data+'</a>
```

подскажите как можно "инициализировать" ссылки после построения приложения, не знаю как правильно назвать это.Спасибо

Comment: Не надо js-ом менять dom (в вашем случае вставлять ссылки), angular придумали в том числе чтобы этого избежать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте! Я думаю, что Вам и не нужно использовать js-ссылки. Просто используйте `routerLink` с параметром.

`<a [routerLink]="['/inventory/item', itemId ]">item {{itemId}}</a>`

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/routing/routeparams.html